# Definition of storage map for stored items

Tags: storage, map, syntax

In the tutorial of learning substrate, a storage map for stored items is defined as follows, in which the symbol `=>` appears, but this specification is not in the standard syntax of rust. How to understand it?

```rust
MyMap get(my_map): map u8 => Vec<u8>;
```

Comment: Could you also link to the substrate docs in question - for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not standard Rust syntax because it makes use of the `#[pallet::storage]` macro. Please have a look at the official documentation for [the macro](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#storage-palletstorage-optional) and the [StorageMap type](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html) for more information.

In short,

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn some_map)]
pub(super) type SomeMap<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, SomeKey, SomeValue, ValueQuery>;
```

sets up a StorageMap with name `SomeMap` for `SomeKey => SomeValue` with getter function `some_map` using the `Blake2_128Concat` hasher. `ValueQuery` states that the resulting value lookup is not wrapped into an Option, which would be the case if you were using `OptionQuery` (default implementation of the QueryKind generic).